# Computing NTTs over Finite Fields with multiplicative order not highly divisible by 2

Tags: number-theory, computer-science, computational-complexity, fast-fourier-transform

I've recently been working with Number Theoretic Transforms and have a question I can't work out the answer for.

**Setup**

Let $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ be a finite field of prime order $q$ and $q = 2m +1$ for $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ an odd integer. I have $\vec{a} \in \mathbb{F}_{q}^{k}$, a vector and I wish to Lagrange interpolate this vector to produce a polynomial $A(x)\in \mathbb{F}_{q}[x]$ such that $A(\omega_{n}^{i})=a_{i}$ for some primitive $n$-th root of unity $\omega_{n}\in\mathbb{F}_{q}^{*}$ (with $n \geq k$).

At least that is the general case, I am really interested in a specific case with
\begin{align*}
q = 21888242871839275222246405745257275088696311157297823662689037894645226208583
\end{align*}
then $q-1$ has prime factorisation
\begin{align*}
2×3^2×13×29×67×229×311×983×11003×405928799×11465965001×13427688667394608761327070753331941386769.
\end{align*}

**My Plan**

I take my vector $\vec{a}$ and find the smallest number $n \geq k$ such that $n | q-1$. This fact guarantees that there is a primitive $n$-th root of unity in $\mathbb{F}_{q}^{*}$, which we shall denote by $\omega_{n}$. I can then pad my vector to length $n$ with zeroes so that now we are dealing with $\vec{a}\in \mathbb{F}_{q}^{n}$ ( I apologise for overloading notation). Then the coefficients of $A(x)$ as a degree $n-1$ polynomial are given by the Number Theoretic Transform of $\vec{a}$. That is
\begin{align*}
A_{j} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_{i}\omega_{n}^{ij}.
\end{align*}

**My Problem**

When reading about NTTs most methods for computing them use the [Cooley-Tukey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm) algorithm and the fact that $n = 2^{s}$ for some reasonably large $s$. My problem is that $q-1$ is not highly divisible by two, or in fact any prime. I thought about using a combination of the [PFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-factor_FFT_algorithm) algorithm and [Rader's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rader%27s_FFT_algorithm) algorithm. This way I can break $n$ down into its prime factorisation and thus convert the problem from computing an $n$-point NTT into a number of $p_{i}$-point NTTs with each $p_{i}$ prime. Then each $p_{i}$ NTT can be computed using [Rader's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rader%27s_FFT_algorithm) algorithm. The fact that $n$ is a divisor of $q-1$ means that for each $p_{i}$ we know that $\mathbb{F}_{q}^{*}$ contains $p_{i}$-th primitive root of unity and so each of these $p_{i}$-point NTTs can be computed in $\mathbb{F}_{q}$.

**Question 1:**
[Rader's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rader%27s_FFT_algorithm) algorithm for a $p$-point NTT with $p$ prime involves computing a [circular convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_convolutionhttps://) which can be done using a $p-1$-point NTT. I can't find a good example or explanation of how this is done so would be very appreciative if somebody could explain it or point me in the correct direction.

**Question 2:**
A related question is then should I break down the $p-1$-point NTT further using the same method as before? Or can this even be done?

Any and all help would be much appreciated, or even suggestions of a better method to the one I have described above.

**Example case**

I know for me sometimes an example helps illustrate the problem. Say we have arrived at $n=2262$ and are computing a $2262$-point NTT (for ease I'll write a $m$-point NTT as $\mathrm{NTT}_{m}$ from now on). We can factorise $2262$ as $2\times 3\times 13\times 29$ and so the [PFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-factor_FFT_algorithm) algorithm tells us that
\begin{align} 
\mathrm{NTT}_{2262}= \mathrm{NTT}_{2}\otimes\mathrm{NTT}_{3}\otimes\mathrm{NTT}_{13}\otimes\mathrm{NTT}_{29}.
\end{align}
Both $\mathrm{NTT}_{2}$ and $\mathrm{NTT}_{3}$ are probably small enough to just compute (in fact $\mathrm{NTT}_{13}$ probably is as well if a bit tedious, but for sake of argument we won't). We can then use Rader's algorithm to compute $\mathrm{NTT}_{13}$ and $\mathrm{NTT}_{29}$, which will require us to compute $\mathrm{NTT}_{12}$ and $\mathrm{NTT}_{28}$ respectively. This is where I get stuck and don't know if I should break down $\mathrm{NTT}_{12}$ and $\mathrm{NTT}_{28}$ in the same way, or even if I can as both $12$ and $28$ are divisible by $4$ and there is no primitive $4$-th root of unity in $\mathbb{F}_{q}^{*}$.

**EDIT**

I have found an alternative solution to my original problem using "ECFFT" as defined in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.08473.pdf). I still do not know the answer for the best way of solving my problem using traditional NTTs.